# How could I serialize an Object without any risk of data corruption ?

Tags: c++, named-pipes

I would like to serialise a basic class like this one :

```
class ProcessData
{
  public:
    ProcessData();
    ProcessData(int processNumber, int threadStatus);
    ~ProcessData();
    int getProcessNumber() const;
    void setProcessNumber(int processNumber);
    int getThreadStatus() const;
    void setThreadStatus(int threadStatus);
  private:
    int _processNumber;
    int _threadStatus;
};
```

and write it to a named pipe.
I use named pipe because I need my child process to send data to my main process.

My main process will read this named pipe and get my object back.

Problem is that a lot of processes could write to the named pipe and this may cause problems.
To serialise this class I thought I could to something like this :

```
write(namePipeFileDesriptor, &processDataClass, sizeof(processDataClass)));
```

Do you think that could work, or is there any other alternatives, except `boost::serialization` ?

Comment: There are plenty of ways of communicating between child and parent processes other than named pipes. You've chosen the worst possible solution, and just about the only one that gives you the problem you mention. Why?

Comment: Are you asking about transport, or about format? Right now I can't tell what your actual question is. What problems are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as reader and writer processes run on the same computer, are compiled for the same target, with same alignment rules, and that data to be sent is POD (or can be considered as POD), you may pipe your data as is, like you suggest to do, and avoid use of a serialization library.
Now, I guess your concern is about atomicity of write/read operations, whatever serialization technique you use, considering that several writer processes can write to the pipe.
Assuming your OS is POSIX-compliant, you can consider any write operation as atomic (ie: no data interleave) as long as the sent data size does not exceed the pipe buffer size.
[Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) states :

> Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe. Writes of greater than {PIPE_BUF} bytes may have data interleaved, on arbitrary boundaries, with writes by other processes, whether or not the O_NONBLOCK flag of the file status flags is set.

The value of `PIPE_BUF` is OS dependant but should be greater than 512 bytes. (It is 4096 bytes for linux OSes.) So, for low sized data, there should be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use [google::protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) library for serialization and deserialization. It's efficient and quick.

For your case, you simply have to create a .proto file

```
// File.proto
message ProcessData
{
  int32 _processNumber;
  int32 _threadStatus;
}
```

After compiling it with `protoc` compiler, you will get "File.pb.h" and "File.pb.cpp", which you have to add to your own project. That's it. Now you can simply serialize and deserialize the required data using various methods provided in those source files.

Another added advantage is that, the same "File.proto" can be used for other languages like Go, Phython, Java, C#, ... Because the message is [de]serialized in language independent way.

Comment: Looks like a great library but I dont want to use external libraries in my project.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov, this is Not an external library in a complete or usual sense. Actually it generates the code for you; e.g. getter/setter, serialize/deserialize and so on. this code will get compiled with your regular code. However the only thing is that, you may have to attach its small static library while linking (probably you don't want that). BTW it's also quite useful when you are sending data over TCP etc.